# Getting a users starred playlist from the Spotify Apps API?

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm trying to get a users starred playlist but for whatever reason Spotify is returning "Invalid playlist URI: spotify:user:jamesw12:starred".

This code snippet will work for all other types of playlists but not starred it seems. Is it just not possible?

```
models.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:jamesw12:starred", function(playlist) {

    console.log("Playlist loaded", playlist);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the library to get the starred tracks.

```
 models.library.starredPlaylist
```

Reference here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/dcdebc652c.html